# NextJS process.env. variables undefined on button click fetch data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js, nestjs

I'm having issue with ENV variables.
On the first request with :

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const posts = await getPosts(1);
  return { props: posts, revalidate: 5 };
};
```

everything goes fine and it fetchs all the data, but on button click i want to fetch new data and i got 404 :

```
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:3000/fr/undefined/ghost/api/v3/content/posts?key=undefined&fields=id%2Ctitle%2Cfeature_image%2Cslug%2Cexcerpt%2Ccustom_excerpt%2Creading_time%2Ccreated_at&include=authors%2Ctags&page=2 404 (Not Found)
```

as you can see env variables result to undefined , i dont know why.
how i fetch the data :

```
  const fetchNewData =async (currentPage)=>{
    console.log(currentPage);
      const post = await getPosts(currentPage)
      console.log(post);
  }
```

---

How i use env

```
export const CONTENTKEY=process.env.contentKey
export const BLOG_API = process.env.blogApiLink;
```

---

```
import axios from "axios";
import {BLOG_API,CONTENTKEY} from "../segret_keys"
export const getPosts = async (page) => {
  const pageUrl =
    BLOG_API +
    "/ghost/api/v3/content/posts/?key=" +
    CONTENTKEY +
    "&fields=id,title,feature_image,slug,excerpt,custom_excerpt,reading_time,created_at&include=authors,tags&page=" +
    page;
      console.log(pageUrl);
      return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: pageUrl,
  }) //&filter=tag:blog,tag:Blog
    .then((res) => {
      return { status: res.status, data: res.data };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.status, err.response.data);
      return { status: err.response.status, data: "" };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) you can use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to expose `Environment Variables` to the Browser:

env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_contentKey=somevalue
```

Use:

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_contentKey
```

**Other approach:**

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    contentKey: process.env.contentKey,
    blogApiLink: process.env.blogApiLink,
  }
}
```

Access to env variables value:

```
import getConfig from "next/config";
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

export const CONTENTKEY= publicRuntimeConfig.contentKey
export const BLOG_API = publicRuntimeConfig.blogApiLink;
```